# Delay between spark executors added and the jobs started to be shedueled

Tags: apache-spark

I have a question regarding what could be the reason of the delay after the executors has been added and before the jobs started to being scheduled. as you see in the figure there is a space after executor 2 has been added.

[image: Delay between executors joining and jobs starting to be schedueled]

Comment: Maybe you are using dynamic allocation of executors? E.g. on AWS EMR it's now on by default.

Comment: yes am using dynamic allocation, but can't we avoid this delay to build a responsive spark app.